# Cannot extract amdgpu tar.xz

Tags: tar

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10, and I can not extract a certain tar file. When trying to extract the file, I get the following message:

```
There was an error while extracting”amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz”
“Not an archive”
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of the command `file amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz`?

Comment: What exact command did you give to produce the error message?  You probably missed a switch for compression type.

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you downloaded the tar file? The file may be corrupt. That way, folks can double check if they are getting the same error.

Answer (score 7):

That particular file is a little *shielded* and I suspect that you have downloaded only a 302 error page. However the following one liner works well enough on my system:

```
wget --referer http://support.amd.com \
https://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ubuntu/amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz
```

Note the use of the `--referer` option. Looks like some effort has been made to prevent people using linking from *outside* the AMD site. This is easy enough, and quite reasonable I believe, to circumvent in this manner.

From the wget man pages:

```
--referer=url
   Include `Referer: url' header in HTTP request.  Useful for retrieving
   documents with server-side processing that assume they are always being
   retrieved by interactive web browsers and only come out properly when
   Referer is set to one of the pages that point to them.
```

The full process on my own system worked as follows:

**1. Initial download:**

```
andrew@illium~$ wget --referer http://support.amd.com \
> https://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ubuntu/amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz
--2017-11-11 16:09:04--  https://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ubuntu/amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz
Resolving www2.ati.com (www2.ati.com)... 23.7.24.254
Connecting to www2.ati.com (www2.ati.com)|23.7.24.254|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 361491288 (345M) [application/x-tar]
Saving to: ‘amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz’

amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 100%[=============================>] 344.74M   794KB/s    in 7m 27s  

2017-11-11 16:16:32 (789 KB/s) - ‘amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz’ saved [361491288/361491288]
```

**2. Subsequent extraction:**

```
andrew@illium~$ tar xvf amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz 
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/Packages
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-amdgpu-pro_1.19.0-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/opencl-amdgpu-pro-icd_17.40-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/amdgpu-pro-lib32_17.40-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libgbm1-amdgpu-pro-base_17.40-492261_all.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libgl1-amdgpu-pro-ext_17.40-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libgles2-amdgpu-pro_17.40-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libgl1-amdgpu-pro-ext_17.40-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/gst-omx-amdgpu-pro_1.0.0.1-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/hsa-ext-amdgpu-pro-finalize_1.1.6-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl-amdgpu-pro_1.19.0-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libllvm5.0-amdgpu-pro_5.0-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx_17.40-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/hsa-ext-amdgpu-pro-image_1.1.6-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/amdgpu-pro-install
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libgl1-amdgpu-pro-appprofiles_17.40-492261_all.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/amdgpu-pro-core_17.40-492261_all.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/llvm-amdgpu-pro-dev_5.0-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libvdpau-amdgpu-pro_17.0.1-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/clinfo-amdgpu-pro_17.40-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/llvm-amdgpu-pro-5.0-dev_5.0-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libgbm1-amdgpu-pro-dev_17.40-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/vulkan-amdgpu-pro_17.40-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libegl1-amdgpu-pro_17.40-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libopencl1-amdgpu-pro_17.40-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libdrm-amdgpu-pro-amdgpu1_2.4.82-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libgbm1-amdgpu-pro_17.40-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/rocm-amdgpu-pro-opencl-dev_17.40-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/rocm-amdgpu-pro-opencl_17.40-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libgbm1-amdgpu-pro_17.40-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/rocr-amdgpu-pro-dev_1.1.6-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-pro_1.3.99-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libdrm-amdgpu-pro-radeon1_2.4.82-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/llvm-amdgpu-pro-5.0_5.0-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/hsa-runtime-tools-amdgpu-pro_1.1.6-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libegl1-amdgpu-pro_17.40-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/llvm-amdgpu-pro-5.0-runtime_5.0-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/hsa-runtime-tools-amdgpu-pro-dev_1.1.6-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/vulkan-amdgpu-pro_17.40-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/llvm-amdgpu-pro-5.0-doc_5.0-492261_all.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libdrm-amdgpu-pro-utils_2.4.82-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/rocm-amdgpu-pro-icd_17.40-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/opencl-amdgpu-pro-icd_17.40-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx_17.40-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libllvm5.0-amdgpu-pro_5.0-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/rocm-amdgpu-pro_17.40-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/llvm-amdgpu-pro_5.0-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/clinfo-amdgpu-pro_17.40-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libvdpau-amdgpu-pro_17.0.1-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/roct-amdgpu-pro-dev_1.0.6-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri_17.40-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/llvm-amdgpu-pro-5.0_5.0-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/amdgpu-pro-dkms_17.40-492261_all.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri_17.40-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/gst-omx-amdgpu-pro_1.0.0.1-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/llvm-amdgpu-pro-runtime_5.0-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libdrm-amdgpu-pro-dev_2.4.82-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/ids-amdgpu-pro_1.0.0-492261_all.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-amdgpu-pro_1.19.0-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/llvm-amdgpu-pro-5.0-runtime_5.0-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libopencl1-amdgpu-pro_17.40-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/rocr-amdgpu-pro_1.1.6-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libdrm-amdgpu-pro-utils_2.4.82-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libdrm2-amdgpu-pro_2.4.82-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/mesa-amdgpu-pro-omx-drivers_17.0.1-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libglamor-amdgpu-pro-dev_1.19.0-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/amdgpu-pro_17.40-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libgbm1-amdgpu-pro-dev_17.40-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/llvm-amdgpu-pro-dev_5.0-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/llvm-amdgpu-pro-5.0-dev_5.0-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/Release
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl-amdgpu-pro_1.19.0-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-pro_1.3.99-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libdrm-amdgpu-pro-radeon1_2.4.82-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/llvm-amdgpu-pro-runtime_5.0-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/mesa-amdgpu-pro-omx-drivers_17.0.1-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libdrm-amdgpu-pro-amdgpu1_2.4.82-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/roct-amdgpu-pro_1.0.6-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/amdgpu-pro_17.40-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libglamor-amdgpu-pro-dev_1.19.0-492261_amd64.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libgles2-amdgpu-pro_17.40-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/llvm-amdgpu-pro_5.0-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libdrm-amdgpu-pro-dev_2.4.82-492261_i386.deb
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261/libdrm2-amdgpu-pro_2.4.82-492261_amd64.deb
andrew@illium~$
```

So hopefully this small wget trick will help you out....

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I fixed it by downloading the file from http instead of https.  Hmmm...

```
wget --referer http://support.amd.com http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ubuntu/amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz
```

---

I'm having this same problem.  No matter how I download the file, even with the given wget command.

```
$ ls -l amd*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 brain brain 144219952 Nov 12 12:19 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar (1).xz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 brain brain 144219952 Nov 12 12:15 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 brain brain 144219952 Oct 25 19:06 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz.1

$ md5sum amd*
c041f34ae4c55e71641d15f0552df609  amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar (1).xz
c041f34ae4c55e71641d15f0552df609  amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz
c041f34ae4c55e71641d15f0552df609  amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz.1

$ file amd*
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar (1).xz: PGP\011Secret Sub-key -
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz:     PGP\011Secret Sub-key -
amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz.1:   PGP\011Secret Sub-key -

$ tar xvf amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz 
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

$ tar xJf amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz 
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

$ cat amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz | xz --decompress
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
```

EDIT:

On further analysis, every time I downloaded from the https url, I would get the last 144219952 bytes of the 361491288 byte file.

```
$ ls -l amd*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 brain brain 144219952 Nov 12 12:19 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar (1).xz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 brain brain 144219952 Nov 12 12:15 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 brain brain 144219952 Oct 25 19:06 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz.1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 brain brain 361491288 Oct 25 19:06 amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz.2
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This post looks like there's an answer hidden somewhere deep in there (use `http` instead of `https`). Can you please trim out the unnecessary parts of the post and make the answer the subject of the post? As it appears you're new here, I'd suggest you read our [tour] as well as our [answer] guide. When you're done, please come back and [edit] your post with all of this in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Do you get a certificate error message from wget with the https address?

Comment: @CharlesGreen That's not the problem, or `tar: xvf: Cannot open: No such file or directory` would be the error. `tar` doesn't take a filename except after the `f` option (that's what the `f` option is for). The `-` is also optional.

Comment: Thanks.  I sent "customer care" a message with a link to this answer (today, 2018-01-02).

Comment: I had to use HTTP instead of HTTPS, because it still corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

The driver archive uploaded in the AMD servers are corrupted. They haven't fixed it yet. May be, we all should report that to AMD.

You can download the file from here, for the time being: https://fichiers.touslesdrivers.com/55256/amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz

Comment: If you use plain HTTP on AMD website to download their driver, it works fine.

Comment: thank you, using this mirror is the only way for me!

Answer (score 0):

When you get the same error on a download that was VIA AMD'S OWN DRIVERS DOWNLOAD PAGE it's not reasonable, it's something BROKEN in AMD's site.
Seeing the SAME ISSUE on 18.50, have seen a LOT of references to the issue, AMD STILL has not fixed the issue and as usual since it's LINUX they don't seem to care.

There is a reason I refuse to buy AMD any more - their drivers situation has been total "we don't CARE, live with our worthlessness" attitude for years now.

Comment: This seems more like a rant than an answer.